# Default value if relationship doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

Using Laravel Datatables package: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

I am eager loading `belongsTo` relationships. However, for some rows, the relationship might not exist, and the `relationship_id` column would be null.

This is causing an issue with datatables:

```
{ data: 'relationship.name' },
```

It throws an error if the relationship doesn't exist. How would I set a default value for this particular column if the relationship was not found? I've tried using `editColumn`, which worked for sorting, but not for searching.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `withDefault()`:

```
public function relationship()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(...)->withDefault(['name' => 'default']);
}
```

Comment: I am using `withDefaults()`, but the issue I have come across is that I am no longer able to use `has()` to check if a related row exists in the referenced table.

Comment: I tried using it with datatable but can't work

Comment: Related documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models

Answer (score 1):

as the documentation of datatables

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent

says you can use

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      "data": "first_name", // can be null or undefined
      "defaultContent": "<i>Not set</i>"
    }
  ]
} );
```

also another answer you can make if condition like this

```
{if (item.relationship != null) {
    return item.relationship;
                        }
    return '';  //this is the default if the relationship doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use withDefault() helper on your relationship if no relationship attached with the model.

**Example:**

The user relation will return an empty App\User model if no user is attached to the post:

```
/**
 * Get the author of the post.
 */
 public function user()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withDefault();
 }
```

if you want to populate the default model with attributes, you may pass an array or Closure to the withDefault method:

```
/**
 * Get the author of the post.
 */
 public function user()
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User')->withDefault([
         'name' => 'Guest Author',
     ]);
 }
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models