# Laravel relation Trying to get property 'id' of non-object exception handeling

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-blade

In my Laravel app there are lots of and different types of relations defined over models, but in view there is a mistake, when ever some attributes are used which are in related object (like $invoice->company->name) there is no check for if that relation exist or like we get that object or not, it should be like this:

```
if($invoice->company){
     {{$invoice->company->name}}
}
```

but I skipped that check and directly accessing that attribute, the problem is that it is not in one relation, it is in every relation and I have used that at a lot of places so editing and adding check every where is not possible

I tried this:
In relation , I added a check that will check if object is returned, if not that return a default dummy object, but that is not applicable as I have to do that same in all relations definition in all models because that will fail in case of something like this:

```
{{$invoice->company->bank->amount}}
```

because in this case amount will throw that error.

I want to find a global solution, that I will create once but it handle all , I tried to make an exception handler that if I get error like Trying to get property of non-object then instead of error, just print N/A.
a single modification in base model may be or a single exception will be very helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752192/default-value-if-relationship-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 1):

let's understand the problem better

the problem you are referring to is not a laravel problem this is a php problem the exception raised is `ErrorException` because most probably you are trying to access a property of `null` this has nothing to do with laravel

the magic get method `__get` that laravel uses to resolve properties and relations already handles if the property or the relation doesn't exist it returns `null`

so when you use `$invoice->company` you have to know that `$company` is an `eloquent` object so when you do `->company` it will call the `__get` method and it will return `null` and there is no problem so far

but once you do `$invoice->company->name` now `$invoice->company` is `null` not an `eloquent` object anymore so when you do `->name` there is no calls for `__get` or anything because there is no object

so what you can do is to benefit from laravel default relation by defining default model for the relations
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models so instead of laravel returning null when the relation is not defined it will return a default eloquent model where it can handle that a child property is not set

```php
/**
 * Get the author of the post.
 */
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withDefault([
        'name' => 'Guest Author',
    ]);
}
 
/**
 * Get the author of the post.
 */
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withDefault(function (User $user, Post $post) {
        $user->name = 'Guest Author';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your php >= 8.0 you can use the null safe operator: (https://php.watch/versions/8.0/null-safe-operator)

```php
{{$invoice->company?->bank?->amount}}
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I cant edit these, there are thousands of places where I have to edit this, thats why I am looking for a global exception

Comment: not sure you can do that in a simple way, since this is an error, not an exception. Also refactoring tools exist. You can maybe modify the error reporting level, but that can hide many other errors so I would not recommend.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps to help with your problem.

1. Create a custom exception that will be thrown when you encounter the error "*Trying to get property of non-object*". This exception will then be caught and handled in your custom exception handler.

```
    namespace App\Exceptions;

    use Exception;

    class NonObjectPropertyException extends Exception
    {
    //
    }
```

2. Customize Laravel's exception handling to catch the `NonObjectPropertyException` and return the default value "N/A" instead of throwing an error. To do this, you can modify the render method in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file.

```
    // app/Exceptions/Handler.php

   use App\Exceptions\NonObjectPropertyException;

   public function render($request, Exception $exception)
   {

    if ($exception instanceof NonObjectPropertyException) {

        return response()->view('errors.non_object_property', [], 500);

    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);

   }
```

3. Create a view that will display the default value ("N/A" in this case) when the exception is caught.
4. To implement this behavior globally, modify the base model that other models extend. You can create a method in the base model that will handle attribute access for related models and throw the `NonObjectPropertyException` if the relation does not exist.

```
    // app/Models/BaseModel.php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Exceptions\NonObjectPropertyException;

class BaseModel extends Model
{
    public function __get($key)
    {
        try {
            return parent::__get($key);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new NonObjectPropertyException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this will work because when the relation is not defined the return will be null so when you try to get a child property it's not `eloquent` model so it will not call `__get`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{{ $invoice->company->bank->amount ?? '-' }}
```

or put `@` at the beginning :

```
{{ @$invoice->company->bank->amount }}
```